# Dax, Create a Table with a CrossJoin and a filter

Tags: dax

Looking for a solution join following tables

```
Table A
Index StartDate EndEnd
1  01/01/2020  01/03/2020
2  01/02/2020  01/04/2020

Table 2
Index Date Error
Z1  01/02/2020  Error 1
Z2  01/02/2020  Error 2
Z3  01/04/2020  Error 3

The Final Table would be
Index StartDate EndDate DateError Error
1  01/01/2020  01/03/2020  01/02/2020  Error 1
1  01/01/2020  01/03/2020  01/02/2020  Error 2
2  01/02/2020  01/04/2020  01/02/2020  Error 2
2  01/02/2020  01/04/2020  01/04/2020  Error 3
```

This is just a sample, the real data i more complex and comes from a ADSL and a ODATA feed, so no way to handle it in the ETL, PowerQuery might be a option but there is no native multiple filter join.

I've seen some samples in DAX but none did perfectly what I wanted....

Comment: You want multiple identical rows?

Comment: Doesn't matter, I will do a distinct if needed

Comment: I was pointing out that your final table in your question has duplicated rows and it's not clear why.

Comment: Sorry, that's a mistake I made, I will edit the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic syntax would look like this:

```
CalculatedTable = 
FILTER ( 
    CROSSJOIN ( TableA, Table2 ),
    [Date] <= [EndDate] && [Date] >= [StartDate]
)
```

Note that you'll need to rename one of the index columns so there's no conflict.

Also note that this produces six rows and filters it down to five (unlike your four) because the `Error 1` row matches both rows from Table A.